# I don't start Jupiter Lab in Anaconda navigator. Its show see below

Tags: python, anaconda

Error executing Jupiter command 'lab': [WinError 5] Access is denied

Comment: What was the command?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it like this:

```
python -m jupyterlab
```